# The multiplication table in javascript should show a table starting from 10 to 19

Tags: javascript, html-table, multiplication

I am trying to print a multiplication table starting from 10 and up to 19. My temporary result is that it basically the same line that is repeating it self..

I tried to use  the table, but it seems that it doesn´t work as desired.. I don´t know how to list all the numbers first from 10 til 19 in a row and in a column and then the product of the rows and columns in the other cells.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body onLoad="gangetabellen()">

      <div id="tabell"></div>

      <script>

      function gangetabellen() {

        var tall1, tall2, produkt; 

        var tabell = "<table style='width:500px'>";

        for (tall1 = 10; tall1 <= 19; tall1++) {
          row += "<tr>";

          for (tall2 = 1; tall2 <= 19; tall2++) {

             produkt = tall1 * tall2;
             tabell += "<td>" + produkt + "</td>";
          }
          tabell += "</tr>";
        }

        tabell += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("tabell").innerHTML = tabell;

      </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

it supposed to show

```
10  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
10 100 110
11 
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Comment: You've missed off the closing `}` of your function for starters

Comment: @LeeTaylor That must be a copying error, because he says he's getting output.

Comment: Should the inner loop also start at `10` instead of `1`?

Comment: yes, that's correct. And thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change two things:

1. Add a } to close the function
2. Change `row += "<tr>";` (undeclared variable) to `table += "<tr>";`

```js
gangetabellen()
```

```html
<div id="tabell"></div>

<script>

  function gangetabellen() {

    var tall1, tall2, produkt; 

    var tabell = "<table style='width:500px'>";

    // If you want a header you should add a for-loop here to add
    // a row with tall2

    for (tall1 = 10; tall1 <= 19; tall1++) {
      tabell += "<tr>";

      // If you want a header to the left you should add it here.

      for (tall2 = 1; tall2 <= 19; tall2++) {

         produkt = tall1 * tall2;
         tabell += "<td>" + produkt + "</td>";
      }
      tabell += "</tr>";
    }

    tabell += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("tabell").innerHTML = tabell;
  }

</script>
```

If you want to display `tall1` and `tall2` at the edges you need to add code for that (and you can use `<th>` instead of `<td>` for "table header". It makes it easier to style the table.

Comment: Hey, it doesn´t work with the header for the row. I tried to add a line tabell+=" "+"<th>"+tall2+"</th>" after the second loop, but it displays the line that repeats itself all over again...

Comment: If you want to add row on top, you need to do it before the first loop. And if you want to add something to the left, you need to add that in the first loop